# Android - "Скриншот" лэйаута не работает при повторном использовании.

Tags: screenshots, android, android-linearlayout, java

Есть LinearLayout, содержимое которого меняется (ширина и высота при этом не меняются). Пытаюсь сделать "скриншот" этого лэйаута кодом

---

```
            String path = Utilities.Paths.SDCARD_PICTURES + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
            utils.MakeScreenshotOfView(mLayout, path);
```

---

```
protected void MakeScreenshotOfView(View v, String PathToSave)
{
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    v.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    try
    {
        Log("Saving a screenshot of View");
        SaveBitmap(b, PathToSave);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

---

```
protected void SaveBitmap (Bitmap b, String path) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Log("Screenshot saved");
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("Can't save screenshot: " + ex.toString());
        throw new Exception (ex);
    }
}
```

---

Первый раз скриншот сохраняется нормально, а второй раз при сохранении он имеет размер 0 байт (файл создался). В логах висит `Screenshot saved`. Почему второй скриншот не сохраняется должным образом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, переписав метод `MakeScreenshotOfView`

```
protected void MakeScreenshotOfView(View v, String PathToSave)
{
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);
    try
    {
        Log("Saving a screenshot of View");
        SaveBitmap(b, PathToSave);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```